# iptables: block specific port by country

Tags: iptables

How could I modify this script:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/block-entier-country-using-iptables/

to block by country for a specific port?

Is it just a matter of changing this:

```
# Drop everything
$IPT -I INPUT -j $SPAMLIST
$IPT -I OUTPUT -j $SPAMLIST
$IPT -I FORWARD -j $SPAMLIST
```

to:

```
# Drop everything
$IPT -I INPUT --dport XXX -j $SPAMLIST
$IPT -I OUTPUT --dport XXX  -j $SPAMLIST
$IPT -I FORWARD --dport XXX  -j $SPAMLIST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add protocol(tcp or udp), for tcp:

```
$IPT -I INPUT -p tcp --dport XXX -j $SPAMLIST
$IPT -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport XXX  -j $SPAMLIST
$IPT -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport XXX  -j $SPAMLIST
```

or(for udp):

```
$IPT -I INPUT -p udp --dport XXX -j $SPAMLIST
$IPT -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport XXX  -j $SPAMLIST
$IPT -I FORWARD -p udp --dport XXX  -j $SPAMLIST
```

must be replaced dport to sport in OUTPUT chain.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh right.  Is there any point of blocking UDP as well? or rather can I combine them into one line?  I assume the answers to that are yes, and no.

Comment: Omitting the `-p tcp` option will block all protocols.  If you don't have the port open for upd it doesn't help, but won't cost much.  I don't know how the port will map to ICMP protocol so you my want to match the protocol using `-p !icmp` to match any protocol other than ICMP